# Unsharpen kernel convolution

Tags: image, image-processing

To sharpen an image we use kernel:

```
|  0 -1  0 |
| -1  5 -1 |
|  0 -1  0 |
```

Is it possible to unsharpen the image once we applied this kernel?

Comment: What do you mean by "unsharpen"? I ask because an "unsharp mask" is a common type of sharpening, but it sounds like you're asking about blurring. You can apply a blur, such as a Gaussian blur, to decrease the sharpness. The kernel would essentially be the same as above, but all values would be positive.

Answer (score 2):

Yes with a caveat!

Yes because this is the easier class of deconvolution -- (just google it, but here's the wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deconvolution).  It is the case where you know the convolution kernel.  The simplest is to divide the frequency domain representation of your filtered data by transfer function and convert back to spatial domain.

The caveat is that that filter amplifies high frequencies.  This can cause truncation.  Truncation is not an invertible operation.

Comment: I guess your answer sums it up, but you should mention that for most practical purposes, the answer to the question is yes.

Comment: @Papouh, I checked again and I was actually wrong.  Seems that filter doesn't attenuate DC.  It enhances high frequencies.  DC stays exactly the same....

Answer (score 0):

In theory it could be done in the frequency domain. The convolution theorem states that convolution in the spacial domain is the same as multiplication in the frequency domain. So take the FFT of both the sharpened image and the kernel you used to sharpen it and divide the FFT image by the FFT kernel. Then take the inverse FFT and you would have your original image back. If you're image isn't stored as floating point truncation errors are going to make this impossible. Also even using floating point image representation the precision errors may yeild zeros in your FFT of the kernel which would cause divide by zero errors.